# Apply css for a specific hovered image

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, foreach

I'm trying to apply the css for a specific hovered image but my code is applying the css for all images when hover only 1 image.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.vidUrl').on('hover', function() {
    $('.thumb-overlay').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.thumb {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.thumb-overlay {
  background-image: url('http://www.denys.be/assets/images/play.png');
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #00000073;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position: relative;">
  <a href="#" class="vidUrl">
    <div class="thumb-overlay"></div>
    <img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/">
  </a>
</div>
<div style="position: relative;">
  <a href="#" class="vidUrl">
    <div class="thumb-overlay"></div>
    <img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/">
  </a>
</div>
```

What is the correct way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is this what you are looking for?**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.vidUrl').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.thumb-overlay').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.thumb {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.thumb-overlay {
  background-image: url('http://www.denys.be/assets/images/play.png');
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #00000073;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position: relative;">
  <a href="#" class="vidUrl">
    <div class="thumb-overlay"></div>
    <img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/">
  </a>
</div>
<div style="position: relative;">
  <a href="#" class="vidUrl">
    <div class="thumb-overlay"></div>
    <img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: @EatenTaik you are welcome, but actually, this can be achieved using CSS also, If you are Interested I can help you with that or you can reffer to other answers as well, CSS is always better than script. :)

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.VIDEO_PARENT_CLASS').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.thumb-overlay').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.thumb {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.thumb-overlay {
  background-image: url('http://www.denys.be/assets/images/play.png');
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #00000073;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="VIDEO_PARENT_CLASS" style="position: relative;">
  <a href="#" class="vidUrl">
    <div class="thumb-overlay"></div>
    <img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="VIDEO_PARENT_CLASS" style="position: relative;">
  <a href="#" class="vidUrl">
    <div class="thumb-overlay"></div>
    <img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. It does applying the css for a specific hovered image but the css keep flashing.

Comment: The result is still the same. I checked from inspect, the `.thumb-overlay` style keep toggle the `display: none;` and `display: block;`

Answer (score 1):

In below code as you wrote. it will apply to all images because of all images have the same class named `".thumb-overlay"`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.vidUrl').on('hover', function(){
            $('.thumb-overlay').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

You should change your code as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.vidUrl').on('hover', function(){
                $(this).find('.thumb-overlay').toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

As we know `$(this)` points current object. So it will apply CSS only on current image.